# When to use Maven for an Android project?

Tags: android, maven

I've been working in `JSF` projects for a couple years; from the standpoint of managing dependencies, `maven` was a huge time saver as projects may have up to 50 dependencies, and a large number of them were the same from project to project.

Now I'm developing `Android` projects, I noticed is unusual having more than 5 dependencies, and they're often vary from project to project; in much cases, I don't have a `jar` to import, but a `Project library`. So I'm managing my android projects dependencies manually, and didn't miss maven so far.

**My questions are**:

Is it always a good practice to use maven for any android project, even if it uses only a couple of external jars? Why? If not, when is it a good a time to think about using maven in a project?

Comment: [According to The Radar](http://www.thoughtworks.com/radar), holding off on Maven is ideal.  [According to Android](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system), they're switching over to Gradle.  Good practice?  That depends.  It's not going to be the way forward, that's for sure.

Comment: Good point @Makoto, thanks for your comment. My doubt is not exactly about using Maven vs other build systems, but about using a build system (no matter Maven or Gradle) or not.

Comment: Isn't Ant a build system too? For demos/samples it is not necessary, but you will sooner or later start adding the same set of dependecies like RoboGuice/Dagger, Otto/EventBus, Volley/Picasso+Retrofit, OkHttp, Robolectric, AndroidAnnotations, etc. to all projects.

Comment: Thanks @MaciejGórski, as far as I know, Ant is not exactly a build system, but a build tool. You may be right, but I've developed relatively large projects, which just used around 5 libraries (i.e. `facebook`, `flurry`, `gracenote`...)